# how do I get the e.target.name from a movieclip

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, addeventlistener

I am trying to `trace` the name of the button that started the `eventListener`. But instead I keep getting

`instance11` instead of the name of the movieClip which should be a number between `0-5`

below is part of my actionscript.

```
 import fl.transitions.Tween;
import fl.transitions.easing.*;
import fl.transitions.TweenEvent;

var columns:Number = 3;
var my_x:Number;
var my_y:Number;
var my_thumb_width:Number = 310;
var my_thumb_height:Number = 440;
var my_groups:XMLList;
var my_total:Number;
var x_counter:Number = 0;
var y_counter:Number = 0;
var title_message:String = "xxxxxx";


var container_mc:MovieClip;

var my_tweens:Array = [];
var container_mc_tween:Tween;
var full_tween:Tween;


var myXMLLoader:URLLoader = new URLLoader();
myXMLLoader.load (new URLRequest("config/menu.xml"));
myXMLLoader.addEventListener (Event.COMPLETE, processXML);

function processXML (e:Event):void {
    var myXML:XML = new XML(e.target.data);
    my_groups = myXML.group;
    my_total = my_groups.length();
    createContainer();
    callThumbs();
}


function createContainer():void {

    container_mc = new MovieClip();
    container_mc.x = 425;
    container_mc.y = 125;
    addChild(container_mc);
    container_mc.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, callSub);
    container_mc.buttonMode = true;



}

function callThumbs():void {

    for (var i:Number = 0; i < my_total; i++) {

        var thumb_url = my_groups[i].@thumb;

        var thumb_loader = new Loader();
        thumb_loader.load(new URLRequest(thumb_url));
        thumb_loader.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, thumbLoaded);

        thumb_loader.name = "thumb_" +i;
        trace(thumb_loader.name);

        thumb_loader.x = (my_thumb_width+10)*x_counter;
        thumb_loader.y = (my_thumb_height+10)*y_counter;



        if (x_counter+1 < columns) {
            x_counter++;
        } else {
            x_counter = 0;
            y_counter++;
        }

    }


}

function thumbLoaded(e:Event):void {
    var my_thumb:Loader = Loader(e.target.loader);
    container_mc.addChild(my_thumb);
    my_tweens[Number(my_thumb.name)]=new Tween(my_thumb, "alpha", Strong.easeIn, 0,1,0.5, true);
    my_thumb.contentLoaderInfo.removeEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, thumbLoaded);
}

function callSub(e:MouseEvent):void {
    trace("IN CALL SUB");
    trace(e.currentTarget.name);

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try setting:

```
thumb_loader.mouseChildren = false;
```

And then tracing:

```
trace(e.target.name);
```

Comment: I made that change and I am still tracing instance11.

Comment: Where do you set the name? I don't see you doing that in the above code.

Comment: Try changing that to thumb_loader.name = "thumb_" + i - maybe it's getting confused because you have an int set for an instance name? I can't remember if flash specifically prohibits that but it might.

Comment: AH ok got you, you are tracing the name of `contentLoaderInfo` not thumb loader, I'll update my answer.

Comment: Great. I also update my code to show all of the script. I pulled some stuff out to save space.

Comment: Oh wait... I'm wrong. Its the click handler calling your code.

Comment: That one worked. Weird I got this part of the script from another gallery script and they did not need mouseChildren.

Answer (score 0):

Try just using `e.currentTarget.name`

The event object keeps track of two targets in the capture/bubbling stack. `e.target` is always the EventDispatcher that *raised* the event, and `e.currentTarget` is the EventDispatcher that is currently *handling* the event.

The child that you actually click *on* on is `e.target`, which is why disabling mouse events for children works. The event isn't bubbling down any father, so `e.target` is the same as `e.currentTarget`.